Rotating -axis relative motion, the acceleration of the origin of the rotating frame
I have a question of 3D kinematics of a rigid body. For relative motion analysis, let's define XYZ as an inertial frame, and xyz with origin O as a rotating frame. If we want to find the time derivative of a position vector $\vec{r}_{P}$ of point P, it can be written as:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}_{P}|_{XYZ} = \frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz}+\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{P/O}
$$
where $\vec{r}_{P}|_{XYZ}$ is $\vec{r}_{P}$ observed from the inertial frame XYZ, $\vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz}$ is $\vec{r}_{P}$ observed from the rotating frame xyz, and $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity of the frame xyz. The second-order time derivative is:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}_{P}|_{XYZ}) = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz})+\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{P/O})
$$
$$
\vec{a}_{P}|_{XYZ}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{P}|_{XYZ} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz}+\vec{\omega}\times\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz} + \vec{\alpha}\times\vec{r}_{P/O}+\vec{\omega}\times\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}_{P/O}
$$
$$
\vec{a}_{P}|_{XYZ}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{P}|_{XYZ} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz}+\vec{\omega}\times\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz} + \vec{\alpha}\times\vec{r}_{P/O}+\vec{\omega}\times(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}_{P/O}|_{xyz}+\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{P/O})
$$
$$
\vec{a}_{P}|_{XYZ}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{P}|_{XYZ} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz}+2\vec{\omega}\times\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz} + \vec{\alpha}\times\vec{r}_{P/O}+\vec{\omega}\times(\vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}_{P/O})
$$
From the above equation, if we want to find the acceleration of the rotating frame origin $\vec{a}_{O}|_{XYZ}$, we can replace P with O in the vectors leading to
$$
\vec{a}_{O}|_{XYZ}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{O}|_{XYZ} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{O}|_{xyz}+2\vec{\omega}\times\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}_{O}|_{xyz} 
$$
--------- (1)
However, if we starts the derivation using O directly instead of P, it turns out to be
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}_{O}|_{XYZ} = \frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}_{O}|_{xyz}
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}_{O}|_{XYZ}) = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt} \vec{r}_{O}|_{xyz})
$$
$$
\vec{a}_{O}|_{XYZ}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{O}|_{XYZ} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec{r}_{O}|_{xyz}+\vec{\omega}\times\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}_{P}|_{xyz} 
$$
--------- (2). Which one is correct between (1) and (2)? My choice is (1) but I am not sure, so please give some comments. Thank you.

If I understood your setup correctly, aren't both velocity and acceleration of $O$ zero in both frames?

O is the origin of xyz which can move such as a reference frame fixed on an aircraft. XYZ is the inertial frame that is fixed to the ground. So, the acceleration of O is not zero.
